# Search for multiple values on two rows on multiple columns Excel

Tags: excel, search

I have the next table (the table has this format),

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTts0.png)

I wanto to search for all the 9's on the row 3 and obtain all the dates on columns A to T for each 9.
In my example the result should be,

29-06-2016

30-06-2016

01-07-2016

02-07-2016

04-07-2016

05-07-2016

06-07-2016

07-07-2016

08-07-2016

09-07-2016

I've tried the index/small formula but the result is only the first date.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: please post your index small formula because if done right that should work.

Comment: {=INDEX($A$1:$T$1,SMALL(IF($V$3=$A$3:$T$3,COLUMN($A$3:$T$3)-COLUMN($A$3)+1),COLUMN(1:1)))}

Comment: See my answer below.  The `COLU‌​MN(1:1)` should be `ROW(1:1)` because it is being copied down and not across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array formula in the first cell:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$T$1,SMALL(IF($A$3:$T$3=$V$3,COLUMN($A$3:$T$3)),ROW(1:1)))
```

Being an Array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: First the `SMALL` its format is `SMALL(Array,k)` k being the sequence number.  The sequence is taken care of by the `ROW(1:1)` which when filled down will iterate from 1 to 2 to 3 ... thus getting the next in line.  The IF() inside the Small creates the array of numbers that meet the criteria.  The Index uses the column number returned by the small to tell it which value to return.

Comment: In my formula i have the -COLUMN($A$3)+1, this is not necessary?

Comment: It is not needed if you start in the first column, which you do.  `-COLUMN($A$3)` = -1 and then you +1 which = 0.  It is there for when you do not start in the first column because INDEX requires a relative number returned.